# Tengwar, tikz and decorations.text

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdftex, compiling

I am trying to write a sentence in tengwar along a circle, and I'm trying to use 
tikz, with a code that looks something like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
\usepackage[all]{tengwarscript}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={\tengwarannataritalic[1]
\tengwa{254}
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna
\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tando\Toore\TTrightcurl
\Tumbar\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna
\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tungwe\Tumbar\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\tengwa{255}}
,text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-100,end angle=100,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this method is that Latex does not outputs a pdf, taking an infinite time to compile.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried putting every character into braces `{...}`?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try, since it's quite laborious, but I noticed it can be solved by simply moving \tengwarannataritalic out of the environment tikzpicture. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes. Font information needs to be wrapped into the text format delimiters, which are `|` initially, i.e.  `|...|`. That is, try `|\tengwarannataritalic[1]|` or `|\tengwarannataritalic|`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do similarly. Minimal file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
\usepackage[annatar]{tengwarscript}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\tikzset{decoration={ text effects along path, 
 text={\Ttinco, \Tparma, \Tcalma, \Tquesse, \Tando, \Tumbar, \Tanga, \Tungwe,
\Tthuule, \Tformen, \Taha, \Thwesta, \Tanto, \Tampa, \Tanca, \Tunque,
\Tnuumen, \Tmalta, \Tnoldo, \Tnwalme, \Toore, \Tvala, \Tanna, \Tvilya,}
}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path [decorate,  decoration= { text effects/.cd,  group letters,  characters={text along path}}] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path [decorate,  decoration= { text effects/.cd,  group letters, reverse text, characters={text along path}}] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\centering


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path [decorate, decoration= {text effects/.cd, group letters,reverse text, characters={text along path}}] (4,0) arc [start angle=-100,end angle=100,radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Reverse text, group letters}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [decorate, decoration= {text effects/.cd,  reverse text, group letters,characters={text along path}}] (0,0)..controls +(45:4cm) and +(225:4cm)..(8,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: 2019-10-15

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
\usepackage[annatar]{tengwarscript}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,decorations.text,calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path,
text={\Ttinco, \Tparma, \Tcalma, \Tquesse, \Tando, \Tumbar, \Tanga, \Tungwe,
\Tthuule, \Tformen, \Taha, \Thwesta, \Tanto, \Tampa, \Tanca, \Tunque,
\Tnuumen, \Tmalta, \Tnoldo, \Tnwalme, \Toore, \Tvala, \Tanna, \Tvilya,}, text align=center,
text effects/.cd,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;}, text along path, text=red!\c!orange},
character widths={text along path, xslant=0, yscale=1}}]
\path [postaction={decorate}, preaction={decorate,
text effects={characters/.append={yscale=-1.5, opacity=0.5,
text=gray, xslant=(\i/\n-0.5)*3}}}]
(0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Using the **xepersian** package for the output Persian language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know why the code I showed didn't work?

Comment: Please see for more information: Section 50.6 Text Decorations, page 645-655, TexLive 2019.

Type in cmd: texdoc pgfmanual.pdf